# Como enviar dos url por medio de AJAX?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

estoy tratando de enviar información a dos archivos diferentes pero solo puedo hacer el post a uno solo, quiero enviarlo a task2,php y tsend.php

```js
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "task2.php",
          data: $(this).serialize(),
          cache: false,
```

Comment: podes crear un `task2ytsend.php` y hacer una sola llamada que traiga una respuesta combinada, con includes y output buffering no haría falta duplicar código

Comment: Si los dos archivos php están en un mismo servidor basta con que el que deba actuar primero contenga `include elotro.php` y recoja su salida antes de devolver la respuesta al cliente. **te complicas sin necesidad**

Comment: Digo lo mismo que @quevedo, aquí lo que cabría preguntar es ¿por qué quieres enviar la petición a dos archivos distintos y no a un sólo archivo desde el cual puedes llamar, incluir, requerir, todos los archivos que necesites? De hecho, aunque pudieras hacerlo, ¿cómo manejarías la respuesta de cada archivo? Ajax no funciona de ese modo, te acepta una sola URL porque luego queda manejar la respuesta que te devuelva esa URL.

Comment: en un archivo guardo los datos y en otro uso la funcion mail(), por alguna razon la funcion mail me "bloquea" la respuesta de parte del servidor en el #result

Comment: en ese caso te convendría insertar el mail en una tabla que luego otro proceso va enviando y eliminando ( o marcando como enviado )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No puedes enviar una peticion a 2 url, en cambio puedes enviar 2 peticiones diferentes

EJ:

```
  $(document).ready( function( ) {
    $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "task2.php",
          data: $(this).serialize(),
          cache: false,
         )};
    $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "tsend.php",
          data: $(this).serialize(),
          cache: false,
         )};
} );
```

Comment: también creando el objeto y cambiando la url se reutiliza en cada llamada

Comment: @aloMalbarez así es como tengo el código: $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#formulario').submit(function(){
  
 var x = confirm("¿Estás seguro que quieres crear esta tarea?");
      if (x){
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "task2.php",
    data: $(this).serialize(),
          cache: false,
         success: function(data) {
          $('#result').html(data).
            fadeIn().delay(1000).fadeOut();
           }
        });//end ajax
  return false;
      }
      
    });
});